# Is HDMI v1.4 cable compatible with HDMI v1.3?

Tags: hdmi

My computer specification requires an HDMI v1.3 cable. Is there some problem if I buy a HDMI v1.4 cable?

Comment: Use of version specification in HDMI cable labeling is deprecated. Cables are supposed to be labeled by supported features instead. Peruse:
[HDMI org site](http://www.hdmi.org/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there won't be any problems. HDMI cables are backwards compatible. [Source](http://hdmi-cables-review.toptenreviews.com/which-hdmi-cable-do-you-need-.html)